# Custom cell not displaying PFImageView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I have a custom `PFTableViewCell` using a NIB. All of my custom labels display, but my `PFImageView` does not. I changed everything to a `UIImageView` just to make sure it wasn't something wrong with my Parse call, but I couldn't get it to work even with setting a static image in my resources.

My cell's class is set as `foodCell` and foodcell.h is set as the owner.

Here is a screenshot showing the imageview on my [NIB](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ikpld73iibbnrxx/Screen%20Shot%202014-01-06%20at%208.31.13%20PM.png)

Here is my foodCell.h to show the outlet of the `PFImageView` :

```
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@interface foodCell : PFTableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSObject *foodCell;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *priceLabel;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *foodDescription;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *foodTitle;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet PFImageView *foodPic;

@end
```

Now here is where I configure my cell. Again, all of my other code here works, except the `foodCell.foodPic.file` :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"foodCell";
    foodCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[foodCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }

    cell.foodPic.file = [object objectForKey:@"foodImage"];
    cell.foodTitle.text = [object objectForKey:@"foodName"];
    cell.foodDescription.text = [object objectForKey:@"foodDescription"];

    NSString *myString = [@"$" stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1@", [object objectForKey:@"foodPrice"]]];

    cell.priceLabel.text = myString;

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per Parse documentation, you should call `loadInBackground` for that `PFImageView`

```
cell.foodPic.file = [object objectForKey:@"foodImage"];
[cell.foodPic loadInBackground];
```

Answer (score 0):

Also call `[PFImageView class]` in your AppDelegate.m `didFinishLaunchWithOptions:` method.

source: https://parse.com/questions/using-pfimageview-with-storyboard