# PFQueryTableViewController with custom cells crash while launching

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, custom-cell, pfquery

I do not understand to this but always when I try to launch my app, I get error. 
Can someone help me? I think it will be maybe something in TableeViewController.m. But i am not sure.
Thanks

TableCell.h

```
#import < Parse/Parse.h >

@interface TableCell : PFTableViewCell
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *cellTitle;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *cellDescript;

@end
```

TableCell.m

```
 #import "TableCell.h"

 @implementation TableCell
 @synthesize cellTitle;
 @synthesize cellDescript;

 - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
 {
     self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
     if (self) {
         // Initialization code
     }
     return self;
 }

 /*
 // Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
 // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
 - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
 {
     // Drawing code
 }
 */

 @end
```

TableeView.h

```
 #import <Parse/Parse.h>
 #import "TableCell.h"
 #import "DetailViewController.h"

 @interface TableeViewController : PFQueryTableViewController {

     NSArray *colorsArray;

 }

 @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *colorsTable;


 @end
```

TableeViewController.m

```
#import "TableeViewController.h"
#import "TableCell.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface TableeViewController ()

      @end

      @implementation TableeViewController @synthesize colorsTable;


      - (void) retrieveFromParse {

          PFQuery *retrieveColors = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Hracky1"];
          [retrieveColors findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
              if (!error) {
                  colorsArray= [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];
              }
              [colorsTable reloadData];

          }];
          [self.colorsTable reloadData];
          [self.refreshControl endRefreshing]; }


      - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
          self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
          if (self) {
          }
          return self; }

      - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
          // Return the number of sections.
          return 1; }

      - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
          // Return the number of rows in the section.
          return colorsArray.count; }


      - (void)viewDidLoad {
          [super viewDidLoad];

          [self performSelector:@selector(retrieveFromParse)];
           }

      - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
          [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
          // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
           }

      - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject
     *)object {

          TableCell *cell = (TableCell * )[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"colorsCell"
      forIndexPath:indexPath];

          NSString * cellTitle = [object objectForKey:@"cellTitle"];
          NSString * cellDescript = [object objectForKey:@"cellDescript"];

          cell.cellTitle.text = cellTitle;
          cell.cellDescript.text = cellDescript;

         return cell; }

      @end
```

Comment: This link helped me to fix this problem.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20963486/custom-cell-not-displaying-pfimageview?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have subclassed the PFTableViewCell and created the properties "cellTitle" and "cellDescription" but you haven't initialized and added them them in TableCell.
There seems to be no reason to subclass the PFTableViewCell if you are not making any changes to it. You can actually just use the normal UITableViewCell.

So, delete "TableCell" and create the cells by using a UITableViewCell:

```
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"ColorsCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}
```

Then you can access the properties "textLabel" and "detailTextLabel" by doing this:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"cellTitle"];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"cellDescript"];
```

Follow this tutorial from beginning to end and you'll get there:

http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-app-backend-parse/

Good luck!

Comment: Can you explain me usage of reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier? Because it is saying me undeclared identifier. Thanks

Comment: See my edited comment. simpleTableIdentifier is basically an NSString that defines the CellIdentifier.

Comment: Thanks for help but it didn`t work for me. I fixed it. Thanks anyways.